# Java: Inheritance vs Generic?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I am trying to figure out the differences/pros + cons/when to use which in the below situation where both Generics and Inheritance seems to provide working alternatives. If I have scenario where I am implementing generic behavior based on some input and returning an output:

**Inheritance**

```java
  // classes
  class Input {
    String id;
  }

  class Output {
    long executionTime;
  }

  class StringUpperInput extends Input {
    String stringToUpper;
  }

  class StringUpperOutput extends Output {
    String upperCaseString;
  }

  // interface
  interface Executor {
    // execute some logic on the input and return the output
    Output execute(Input i);
  }

  // implementation
  class StringUpperExecutor implements Executor {
    @Override
    public Output execute(Input i) {
      String upper = ((StringUpperInput) i).stringToUpper.toUpperCase();
      StringUpperOutput output = new StringUpperOutput();
      output.upperCaseString = upper;
      // set general stuff like execution time etc
      return output;
    }
  }
```

**Generics**

```java
  class GenericInput<I> {
    String id;
    I inputObj;
  }

  class GenericOutput<O> {
    long executionTime;
    O outputObj;
  }

  class StringUpperInputParam {
    String stringToUpper;
  }

  class StringUpperOutputResult {
    String upperCaseString;
  }

  interface ExecutorGeneric<I, O> {
    GenericOutput<O> execute(GenericInput<I> input);
  }

  class StringUpperGenericExecutor implements ExecutorGeneric<StringUpperInputParam, StringUpperOutputResult> {

    @Override
    public GenericOutput<StringUpperOutputResult> execute(GenericInput<StringUpperInputParam> input) {
      GenericOutput<StringUpperOutputResult> resultWrapper = new GenericOutput<>();
      StringUpperOutputResult result = new StringUpperOutputResult();
      result.upperCaseString = input.inputObj.stringToUpper.toUpperCase();
      resultWrapper.outputObj = result;
      
      // set general stuff like execution time, etc
      return resultWrapper;
    }
  }
```

Above is an example of a "Executor" that will take an input string and returns the upper case of it. I want to write a service that will have list of such executors and will pick one based on some criteria and then pass the input object to the specific executor generically and get back an output. For this kind of scenario, which of the above two approaches work best? What is the advantage of one over the other? It seems both can work so I guess I'm looking for the "correct" way to do it.

Comment: First, for something simple like this, don't over look a simple method call.  `String.toUpperCase()` does this with no generics and no inheritance.  Simple. For your question, if a class is truly generic -- that is it works identically for any type -- then you can use generics.  Think `ArrayList`, which works the same no matter what type you put in it.  If a class works differently based on type, that's inheritance (or more precisely polymorphism).

Comment: Generics and inheritance are not mutually exclusive.  There are times when they work hand in hand.

Answer (score -2):

In a situation like that, I would use generics.

While you might be successful with inheritance, there are a few disadvantages.

If you have a container, you might want to use a generic type since that's what generics are made for.

#### additional cast

Let's assume you have multiple executors with different types.

If you use inheritence, you would need to explicitely cast it every time you want to get the result:

```java
StringUpperOutput output = (StringUpperOutput) executor.execute(input);//or call some method (which has no idea about the executor) that in turn calls executor.execute
```

Similarly, you have these casts in your `execute` methods. Someone could supply invalid input.

With generics, there would still be implicit casts but the compiler checks whether you are using matching types and automatically inserts the tasks.

#### may be final

If you use inheritence, you extend the classes. You might not want everyone to extend any class you write so you might want to make these classes `final`. This doesn't work with generics.

#### More code

With the inheritance approach, you would need to create an input/output/executor class for every input/output type/operation.

#### different situations

Generics are made for different situations than inheritance. If you want to extend the functionality of some class, you might want to use inheritance. If you just want to specify the type outside of the class, you probably want to choose generics.

You can also use them together as suggested by [John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) [in the comments of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77628774/java-inheritance-vs-generic/77628882#comment136855954_77628774). This may be useful if your `Input`/`Output` classes should have additional functionality. For example, you could add a method to `Input` checking whether that input is valid:

```java
class GenericInput<I> {
    String id;
    I inputObj;

    boolean checkValid(){
        return true;//generally, any input is valid but you can create specific subclasses and checks there.
    }
}
```